# How quickly can we multiply hypercomplexes?

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, hypercomplex-numbers

If we start with a hypercomplex number with $2^n$ entries, how quickly can we multiply it by another hypercomplex number, *modulo a prime*?

**EXAMPLE**

For example, with $n=1$, we get the complex numbers.  So we are multiplying a number, say $a=a_r + a_i i$ by $b=b_r + b_i i$ which equals: $$(a_r\cdot b_r - a_i \cdot b_i) + i(a_r \cdot b_i + a_i \cdot b_r)$$

So it seems we would need 4 multiplications.  In general, with a naïve algorithm, it seems we need $(2^n)^2$ multiplications.

**MOTIVATION**

I believe I've found a faster way to do the multiplications, but maybe there's already a better way.  So I'm wondering, how quickly can we multiply two hypercomplex numbers together, **modulo a prime**?

Comment: What naive algorithm needs $2^{2^n}$ multiplications?  Why not $(2^{n})^2$?

Comment: @ErickWong:  You're right - I'm sorry - I'll fix the number.  My question still stands, as I think I can get something faster than $n^2$ - very close to linear.